# Roundrobin implementation of offset value in Golang for number of records fetched from couchbase n1ql query

Tags: multithreading, go, multiprocessing, migration, couchbase

How to add the RoundRobin logic for offset limit? Only using 10 threads i should be able to create offset value and assign offset value in roundrobin way between 10 threads. I am fetching 3 million records from couchbase which internally causing n1ql timeout.

```
    query := "select count(1) as count from `" + configuration.BucketName + "` where APPID='" + configuration.APPID + "'"
    var countVariable int = 0
    countVariable = countVariable + 1
    fmt.Println("countVariable value: ", countVariable)
    rows, err := cluster.Query(query, &gocb.QueryOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var row map[string]interface{} //To fetch n1ql query output
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Row(&row)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    countTotal := int64(row["count"].(float64))
    fmt.Println("countTotal num value : ", countTotal)
    if countTotal == 0 {
        fmt.Println("No rows returned")
        os.Exit(3)
    }
    float_offset_count := math.Ceil(float64(int(countTotal) / configuration.Limit))
    offset_count := int(float_offset_count) + 1
    fmt.Println("offset_count :", offset_count)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {    // should be only 10 threads
        wg.Add(1)
        //fmt.Println("Goroutine :",i)
        offset_limit := configuration.Limit * i  // limit is 20000
        go n1qlFetch(i, &wg, offset_limit)   // This function contains n1ql query which fetches 3 to 4 ,million records
    
    }
```

I am trying implement the logic as below

```
total documents - 2000000

limit :20000
offset : 2000000/20000 = 100
threads :10

so offset value will be as below:
0
20000
40000
60000
80000
100000
.
.
.
.
2000000

thread 1 [0,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000,120000,140000,160000,180000,200000] --> 0 to 2lac records 
thread 2  [220000,240000,260000,280000,300000,320000,340000,360000,380000,400000,420000]
thread 3  ""should be divided same as above
thread 4  ""should be divided same as above
thread 5  ""should be divided same as above
thread 6  ""should be divided same as above
thread 7   ""should be divided same as above
thread 8   ""should be divided same as above
thread 9   ""should be divided same as above
thread 10  ""should be divided same as above

for each ele in offsetlist:
      offset = ele
```

Comment: Index has to scan repeatedly and skip the offset. https://blog.couchbase.com/offset-keyset-pagination-n1ql-query-couchbase/
The following approach will perform better
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default(APPID, META().id); start $id value "" for done := false ; !done ; SELECT META().id FROM default WHERE APPID = "appid" AND META().id > $id LIMIT 100000; If no results done = true for each id value call function that gets document using bucket.get() and do required  operations. The above call can be done multiple threads parallelize it. set $id value last value of the select repeat next set of values

Comment: @vsr i need limit and offset both in select count(1) , in the remaining code i have one more main n1ql query which fetches other columns and meta().id